# How to sum two columns of different tables in sql

Tags: sql-server, join, sum

I created two tables **book** and **cd**

`**Books**    **Book_id**    **author**     **publisher**   **rate**
angular2         132           venkat            ts           1900
angular          160           venkat            ts           1500
html 5           165           henry             vk           1500
html             231           henry             vk           2500
css              256           mark              adobe        1600
java             352           john              gulberg      4500
c#               450           henry             adobe        1600
jsp              451           henry             vk           2500
ext js           555           kv venkat         w3           5102
html             560           kv venkat         gulberg      5000
java2            561           john              gulberg      9500
java8            651           henry             vk           1650
js               654           henry             ts           2500
java             777           babbage           adobe        5200
phython          842           john              ts           1500
spring           852           henry             w3           6230
spring           895           mark              tut          4250
ext js           965           henry             gulberg      4500`

```
book_id              Cd_name           Cd_price
132                  angular2          500
132                  angular1          600
132                  angular basics    600
132                  angular expert    900
160                  begineer_course   1200
160                  angular_templates 500
165                  html_tutorials    900
165                  bootstrap         1000
256                  css styles        650
256                  expert css        900
555                  extjs             1200
555                  exjs_applications 500
777                  core java         2500
777                  java swing        4500
777                  java tutorials    1500
842                  phython           650
852                  spring            900
852                  spring mvc        900
```

In the above two tables i want to join the books,author,cd_name and the total cost of book and cd for each id.

**Expected Output**

```
Books       Book_id     author  cd_name       total price
angular2    132         venkat  angular2         2400
angular2    132         venkat  angular basics   2100
angular2    132         venkat  angular expert   2800
java        777         babbage core java        7700
```

Like the above result i need to get the total cost for all the books and cd

Comment: I'd suggest to rather use the simple "rate + cd_price AS total_price" instead of any SUM function. In order to do so, simply join the two tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pls post your query(ies)?

Comment: select books,author,cd_name,rate,cd_price

   from book

   join cd

   on book.book_id = cd.book_id

   where (book.rate + cd.cd_price) as total_price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case not all books had a CD:

```
SELECT A.Books
       , A.Book_ID
       , A.Author
       , B.CD_Name
       , A.rate+COALESCE(B.Cd_price,0) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM BOOK A
LEFT JOIN CD B ON A.BOOK_ID = B.BOOK_ID
```

Question's author evidenced that "The table name is book not Books"

I used originally BOOKS as a "suggestion" because (usually) tables name are plural.

Comment: Why this code is not working ------- ------- select books,author,cd_name,rate,cd_price
   from book
   join cd
   on book.book_id = cd.book_id
   where (book.rate + cd.cd_price) as total_price

Comment: The syntax is wrong: you can't write "WHERE (book.rate + cd.cd_price) as total_price".  You can't use AS in WHERE.   Instead you could write, for example,  "WHERE (book.rate + cd.cd_price) > 100"  (P.S. Bracket can be eliminated)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select books, b.book_id, author, cd_name, (b.rate+c.cd_price) as total_price from book b
join cd c on b.book_id = c.book_id
```

Comment: i understood the syntax but i am new to this and coundnt understand the purpose of    "b.book_id" ( why do we need b. ) and using the same " b. " again as b.rate , and again somthing like this in the table name " join  cd c " (what does that extra ' c ' do)

Comment: @docpinocchio Sorry for the late reply. When joining tables you can give an alias(short name) to the table, and use this alias to tell the SQL that we want to use the column from the specific table. The main purpose of using this is to remove ambiguity as SQL cannot decide on which table column to use if both tables have a column with the same name. You can choose not to use an alias for other columns. But it is recommended for clarity.